# How do I set up Gmail to block me from checking more than once a day?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I want to limit the number of times a day I check my e-mail (for many reasons, finding balance with technology, improving my personal productivity, etc).  However, I lack the self control to check only once a day.

Is there a technical way or a setting in Gmail to limit my checking of Gmail to once a day?

I currently use Google Apps for my domain, through which I use Gmail for my e-mail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no option like that in Gmail itself, but you can achieve what you want with browser plugins such as [StayFocusd](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji) for Chrome. There are equivalents for Firefox as well, though I'm not entirely sure about Internet Explorer or other browsers.

This specific plugin doesn't let you set up a specific number of allowed visits and goes for limiting time spent on the sites instead, though you could visit Gmail and just use the plugin to block the site for the rest of the day, but you get the idea.